# What does * in front of function name mean in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

What exactly does putting an `*` in front of function name mean?

Also how are these two codes different from one another?

```
int *modify_array(int *array, int size);

int (*modify_array)(int *array, int size);
```

Comment: First one: `modify_array` is a function that returns pointer to int; second one: `modify_array` is a pointer to functions that return int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int *modify_array(int *array, int size);
> int (*modify_array)(int *array, int size);
> ```

First one: `modify_array` **is a function** that accepts two arguments and **returns a pointer to an int**.
Second one: `modify array` **is a pointer to a function** that accepts two arguments and **returns an int**.

Example, names changed

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *fx(int *, int); // function prototype
int (*fp)(int *, int); // variable declaration
int *fx(int *a, int n) { // function definition
    return a+n; // address of a[n]
}
int fx2(int *a, int n) { // function definition, prototype, and declaration
    return a[n];
}
int main(void) {
    int ar[] = { 0, 42, 0, 0 };
    fp = fx2; // make the pointer point to a function of the right kind
    printf("%p %d\n", fx(ar, 1), fp(ar, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Note about calling a function through the pointer `fp`: you can dereference the pointer or use the pointer directly

```
#include <math.h>
double (*fx)(double) = sin;
sin(3.1416/4) == (*fx)(3.1416/4) == fx(3.1416/4);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// declares a function which returns an int (usually 4 bytes)
int modify_array_1(int *array, int size);

// declares a function which returns an pointer (usually 8 bytes)
// that pointer is the memory address of a 4-byte int
int *modify_array_2(int *array, int size);

// declares a variable of type pointer (usually 8 bytes) which points to a function
// the function has the signature int SOMETHING(int *array, int size)
int (*modify_array_3)(int *array, int size);
// now, because modify_array_1 has that signature, you can run this:
modify_array_3 = modify_array_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line, `modify_array` is a function that returns a pointer to int;
But your second line is a pointer to function, so `modify_array` is a pointer to functions that return an `int` and accept two parameters, `array` and `size`.